# Gmail Email Table Spacing

Tags: email, gmail

I know this horse has just about been beat to death.. but I've got a Gmail table spacing issue that is just stumping me this morning.

```
<td valign="top">
        <img src="###/enewsletter_layout_v3_18.jpg" alt="" />
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background: #000; width: 700px; margin: 0 0 0 8px; text-align: center; color: #fff;">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" style="background: #890000; height: 50px; padding: 10px 15px; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;">
                New Patient Special Offer <br/>
                Save $$$
                </td>                   
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" style="background: #000; height: 50px; padding: 5px 15px 15px 15px;">
                    <h1 style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;">Do you have a question?</h1>
                    If you have read anything in this newsletter and have any questions or would like to 
                    discuss further, please contact <br/>
                    The Centre at (555) 555-5555 
                </td>                   
            </tr>           
        </table>

    </td>
```

No matter what I do, the first image in the table there (layout_v3_18) **always** has spacing under it. About 2-3 pixels of white space in Gmail. Happens on a couple other images in the email, but the rest work fine. No matter how many times I compare the tables, it won't work.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I've actually run into this problem a lot recently. The code we found that works best (read: looks consistent in the most mail clients) is the following:

```
<img src="###" style="display: block;" />
```

Just add the display: block to every image and it fixes the problem.

Comment: This should have been the answer. display:block is far better for cross email client, cross browser and mobile native experience, also found border-collapse: collapse for the table style to be good too.

Comment: Great solution! I was looking for this fix for a while!

Comment: Just a little reminder: Don't just copy paste **style="display: block;"** specially when you have your own **style** because, obviously, it won't work. :)

Comment: Now my problem has become, how do I get Outlook to ACTUALLY send the style tag to gmal because it doesn't appear on the other end

Answer (score 4):

In answer to my own question (in case someone else has a similar issue), I finally found the issue (or a solution anyways).

I added a `style="float: left"` to the image itself, which magically fixed it.
Alternatively, using "display: block" tends to have a similar result if used on all images, but the float seems to clear the spacing specifically for GMail when it's working perfectly fine elsewhere.

Comment: Excellent! Just what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Gmail can add white space around any table, including nested tables.

Although a bit of a hack adding the following as an inline style to the table removes the white space:

```
style="font-size:0.0em;" ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, I added below line

```
  style="line-height:1px;"
```

in the td tag above.

In my html template in filelist.

Answer (score 2):

Using `display:block` on images reduced some space between image cells but didn't remove all gaps.

Adding the deprecated cellpadding/cellspacing attributes on the parent table (`<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">`) those last gaps were gone too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and did all the above style options but nothing worked. I made the table height shorter and it removed all the spacings.

Comment: How does this constitute an answer? This is a comment.